# How to append column data, row wise in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

How can i copy the data from different columns separated by blank column in between to rows. i have tried using transpose but didnt get the desired output.

**How data is present in excel**

[image]

**Desired Output :**

[image]

Comment: There is no built in way to do this. You will either need to copy/paste to get your desired results or write some relatively complex VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Transpose
Dim area as Range
Dim nr as long
Applicaiton.Screenupdating = False
nr =1
For Each area in Range("D1",Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).SpecialCells(xlcellTypeConstants).areas
area.copy
cells(nr,5).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
nr = nr + 1
Next area
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the above script worked